# Automatically boot Kernel after we skip the auto boot in Uboot

Tags: u-boot

I have an application which requires connecting two F&S boards with their default Uboot consoles connected to each other externally. This prevents them from loading the kernel since both of them locks each other by sending characters, since each uboot is waiting with "Hit any key to skip the autoboot".

I don't want to recompile the uboot to change the default console or silent the console. Is there any other solution so that once the uboot has been prevented from auto booting can reenter into the kernel boot state, for instance like booting after a predefined time?

Comment: You could change **bootdelay** in the environment to disable autoboot.  *"...reenter into the kernel boot state"* -- Huh???

Comment: I have tried setting the bootdelay to zero. Still if the boards turn on simultaneously Kernel is not loaded.

Comment: *"I have tried setting the bootdelay to zero."* -- Wrong.  From the U-Boot documentation: "Set this variable to -1 to disable autoboot."

Comment: Can you please give links to the documentation which explains this?

Comment: In my project both devices are prevented from auto booting.....I dont want to disable the autoboot. I want to retry auto booting if it is deprived of autobooting due to console characters from other devices during booting